# carry out firebase authentication from a service class?

Tags: java, android, service, firebase-authentication

I have an activity for new users that consists of 3 edit texts, one for entering their email address, setting their password and entering receipt numbers. Before signing up using firebase users are supposed to pay for services through the banks and use the receipt number to confirm payment in the app, when the user clicks the sign up button the entered receipt number is sent to the private server, which sends back an ID. This all works, but I am trying to send the parsed ID number from the json response along with the users inputed email address and password to a service class, where a sign up method starts after 30 seconds. In the sign up method, the ID is sent to the server for verification and when a valid json response is received from the server, it creates a new firebase user using the string password and email address passed from the main activity. I however get a null pointer error in the same line where the email address and password is put in the firebase create new user method. Below is how I get the email address and password from the main activity

```
public Signupservice() {
 String a;
 String b;
}
...... 
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags , int startId){

     a=intent.getStringExtra(FILENAMED);
     b=intent.getStringExtra(FILEEXD);
 ...... 
  firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(a, b).addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "signupunsuccessful: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"suucessfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

However I receive the following error from the logcat in reference to the first line of code from the method create user with email and password

```
2019-10-02 20:40:15.539 20184-20184/com.chomba.haroldking.kupa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.chomba.haroldking.kupa, PID: 20184
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.chomba.haroldking.kupa.Signupservice.parseData(Signupservice.java:159)
```

Below is how string is sent to the service class

```
 Intent startServiceIntent=new Intent(Signupuser.this,Signupservice.class);
    startServiceIntent.putExtra(FILENAMED,emailIDfed);
         startServiceIntent.putExtra(FILEEX,gce);
         startServiceIntent.putExtra(FILENAMEDD,paswdfed);
```

Please render assistance

Comment: `firebaseAuth = null` Where you initialized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firebaseAuth` is null.  It looks like you have not assigned it before first using it.  Make sure to assign it first: `firebseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`.